# How to calculate energy in two-band Hubbard model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

It might be a very easy question for you, but I am confused and I need helps.

In the simplest Hubbard model at one-dimensional lattice, I ignore the $U$ term and only remain the hopping term.
$$H=-t\sum_{<ij>}{c^{\dagger}_{i} c_{j}}$$
where $c^{\dagger}_i$ and $c_i$ are creation operator and annihilation operator on site $i$, respectively.

And the Fourier transformation is defined as
$$c_{k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_{i}{c_{i} e^{i k r_{i}}}$$
here, the summing index $i$ is subcript, and it is different from the imaginary unit $i$.

Finally, we get
$$H(k)=\sum_{k}{\epsilon_{k} c^{\dagger}_{k} c_{k}}$$
by sum over all site index $i$, and $<ij>$ gives geometric factor which is included in energy $\epsilon_{k}$.

-------o-------o---------------o-------o----

```
    |<-a->|<----b---->|

         bilattice
```

Here, my qusetion is, for bilattice, $\epsilon_{k}$ should give two energy bond -- one $k$ should give two differnet energy. I don't know how to calculate it.

Could you help me?

Comment: It is not clear what you call a bilattice. Do you have a formula (in real space) for it ?

Answer (score 3):

When considering a bilattice you need to distinguish two type of sites.

```
       A       B               A       B
-------o-------o---------------o-------o----

       |<--a-->|<------b------>|
```

For instance you can denote the two kind of sites with letters $A$ and $B$ as it is shown above. Then you have now two different creation and destruction operators . $c_{iA}^{\dagger}$ and $c_{iA}$ in order to create or annihilate a particle in $A$ sites and $c_{iB}^{\dagger}$ and $c_{iB}$ for $B$ sites.

You have to be careful with indices $i$. With a simple lattice the sites had indices like that:

```
       A       A       A       A       A
-------o-------o-------o-------o-------o
      i-1      i      i+1     i+2     i+3
       |<--a-->|<--a-->|<--a-->|
```

But know the indices are different since there is two kinds of sites:

```
       A       B               A       B
-------o-------o---------------o-------o----
       i       i              i+1     i+1
       |<--a-->|<------b------>|
```

All this changes expressions of Fourier transforms and hamiltonian:
$$
c_{kA}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V/2}}\sum_{i}{c_{iA} e^{i k r_{i}}} \quad \text{where} \quad
r_i=i*(a+b)
$$
$$
c_{kB}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V/2}}\sum_{i}{c_{iB} e^{i k r_{i}}} \quad \text{where} \quad
r_i=i*(a+b)+a
$$
**EDIT**:The volume of the system has to be divided by two in Fourier transforms since there is now two sites in each primitive cell (there were only one before). **END EDIT**

The hamiltonian now takes the form:
$$
H=-\sum_{i}{t_s (c^{\dagger}_{iA} c_{iB} + c^{\dagger}_{iB} c_{iA})+t_l (c^{\dagger}_{iB} c_{(i+1)A} + c^{\dagger}_{(i+1)A} c_{iB})}
$$
where I have considered a one-dimensional problem. Since the distance between sites is not always the same, you might want to consider two different hopping parameters: $t_s$ for short jumps and $t_l$ for long ones.

**EDIT:** I had forgotten terms in the Hamiltonian, nearest neighbor hopping terms must be present in both ways $(A,i)\rightarrow (B,i)$ and $(B,i) \rightarrow(A,i)$. The *long* jumps are $(A,i+1)\rightarrow (B,i)$ and $(B,i)\rightarrow (A,i+1)$.
**END EDIT**

If you want to obtain a diagonal form for your Hamiltonian, you can try to find a $2\times2$ matrix $M$ such that:
$$
H=-\sum_{k}{(c^{\dagger}_{kA} c^{\dagger}_{kB})M\binom{c_{kA}}{c_{kB}}}
$$
$M$ will contain hopping parameters $t_s$ and $t_l$, once you have diagonalized $M$ your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried your method, and got an answer. I calculate the matrix $M=\left(
\begin{array}{}
0 & t_s e^{ika} + t_l e^{-ikb} \\
t_s e^{-ika} + t_l e^{ikb} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and energy is $E(k)=\pm |t_s e^{ika} + t_l e^{-ikb}|$. Am I right?

Comment: @qfzklm I had forgotten hermitian conjugate terms in the Hamiltonian, those terms represent the other way for a jump between two sites. I guess you'll have to preform the calculations again... Sorry. Also don't forget to divide the volume/number of particles by 2 in your Fourier transforms.

Comment: @qfzklm Actually you were right, you didn't forgot any terms. I check your $M$ matrix with the edited hamiltonian and it works (don't forget prefactors depending on volume). But I find a different energy $E(k) = \pm \sqrt{t_s^2 + t_l^2 + 2t_s t_l \cos(k(a+b))}$.